# Why url rewrite is not working in symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony

I want to have a user friendly url such as "http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev/" instead of "http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/" . I have tried editing the htaccess but still does not work. My htaccess in the web dir is :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I suppose it should have worked.. How can I make this work and what is the problem in the htaccess codes if any?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add into your vhost configuration following lines:

```
<Directory "/path/to/docroot">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Because it allows your local .htaccess to override vhost configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `RewriteRule ^app_dev(.*)$ app_dev.php [QSA,L]` before `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]`.

Answer (score 0):

You must enable the RewriteEngine in the apache configuration:

`sudo a2enmodule rewrite`

Regards,
Max